# Search for string in paragraph and underline it

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, indexing

I have a paragraph, e.g.

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum <b>amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</b> dolor sit nonumy eirmod  tempor 
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, <i>sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
et justo duo dolores et ea rebum</i>. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
</p>
```

and a string like `"Lorem ipsum amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr"`.
I want to achieve underlining this particular string in the original paragraph with Javascript.

I think I need to insert a span with a class/id (-> CSS: text-decoration:underline) but I don't know how to determine the correct indices within the paragraph (ignoring any `<b>`, `<i>` etc. in the string search but including them wrt the index of the span).

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
//get the inner contents of the element
var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

//replace the text you want with that same text surrounded by <u> tags
var newtext = text.replace(/Lorem ipsum <b>amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr/g, "<u>Lorem ipsum <b>amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</u>");

//put the new underlined text back into the element
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = newtext;
```

```html
<p id="text">
Lorem ipsum <b>amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</b> dolor sit nonumy eirmod  tempor 
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, <i>sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
et justo duo dolores et ea rebum</i>. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
</p>
```

### **UPDATE:**

Use this method to underline `Lorem ipsum amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr` whether there are other tags (`<b>` or `<i>`) or not:

```js
//get the html contents of the text
var var1 = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

//add <span class="underline"> before the first word of the sring you want to replace
var var2 = var1.replace(/Lorem/gi, '<span class="underline">Lorem');

//add </span> after the last word of the sring you want to replace
var var2 = var2.replace(/elitr/gi, "elitr</span>");

//put text with <span> back into the element
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = var2;

//get the number of all elements with class name of underline
var var3 = document.getElementsByClassName("underline").length;

//get the number of </span> closing tags in the element
var var4 = (document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.match(/<\/span>/g)).length;

//get the number of unclosed tags
var var5 = var3 - var4;

//close any unclosed span tags
var var6 = "</span>" * var5;
var var6 = var6 + "</p>";
document.getElementById("text").outerHTML.replace(/<\/p>/gi, var6);

//get the number of all elements with class name of underline
var var7 = document.getElementsByClassName("underline").length

//run the inner functions the number of times there are elements with class name of underline
for (let i = 0; i < var7; i++) {
  //get the element with class name of underline
  var var8 = document.getElementsByClassName("underline")[i];
  
  //if it's not the sring you want to underline, remove the <span class="underline"></span> from around it
  if (var8.innerText !=  "Lorem ipsum amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr") {
    var var9 = underline.innerHTML;
    underline.outerHTML = var9;
  }
}
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">
Lorem ipsum <b>amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</b> dolor sit nonumy eirmod  tempor 
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, <i>sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
et justo duo dolores et ea rebum</i>. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
</p>
```

Comment: Two problems: what if the text you want is split by e.g. a span or similar element? And the u element should no longer be used for underline, use CSS instead, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u

Comment: for CSS use `<span style="text-decoration: underline"></span>` instead of `<u></u>`

Comment: I don't have any <b> tags etc. given in the string though, so how do I find this substring of the paragraph - if present - in the first place?

Comment: I've updated the question, check and see if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks Johna for your effort, I could use some of your answer. It still only works for that particular string, so that would have to be generalized to be adaptable for any input. You don't have to fix it, I've got it to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

`const text = YourString.replace(/\bMySearch\b/sg, '<u>$1</u>');`

Comment: How is this code supposed to be used?

Comment: inside a script tag

Comment: thanks for your answer, how does that work? the foo is the string I'm looking for?

Comment: yes and `string` is your paragraph

Comment: Anf if MySearch was a variable, how what I include that in the expression? Most answers online suggest "new RegExp(... etc.)" but I'd be interested if it works with a one-liner as well.

Comment: if the needle is a variable its more flexible and you'd need to use `new RegExp()`

Comment: So ```var pattern = "/\b\b/sg";
var regexp = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
text.replace(regexp, '<u>$1</u>');```?

Comment: no you'd do this: `const re = new RegExp(\`\b${needle}\b\`, gi)`; Then `text.replace(re, '<u>$1</u>');`